# I need help to do correlation analysis in R

Tags: r

I want to do a correlation analysis in R. About 10 columns and 6000 rows are present in the data set. One of the columns is ‘name of the centre’. Six centres are listed under this column ( not numerical value). Other two columns I am interested is number of Activity (number) and hours of stay(number).

I wanted to see the relationship between the activity and hours spent in each centres.

I wish to have the result for each centres.

I have used this comment to get a scattered plot with correlation value. I do not find a way to do something like facet_wrap in ggplot.

```
ggscatter(tpro, x = "Activity", y = "Hour" 
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "Activity", ylab = "Hours")
```

ps: i am new to R

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem right you want to see each of the two (hours spent and activity) separately for each centres. I am not sure how do do this directly in the data as is. You can try to first spread the data with the spread function of the tidyr package.

spread(data, key=centre, value=column that will populate data for each centre)